# How to Implement our own (customize) server code for Openfire

Tags: android, xmpp, openfire

I am making an android project for which I need to use GCM CCS. So I chose openfire server 
as third party app server. I have Installed and configured openfire server. I have sample app server written in Java, using the Smack library with me https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html.

Now I want to implement this code in openfire server. I have followed "Building source code" from igniterealtime documentation (http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/source-build.html#jar).

But still dont get any idea how to edit(write/implement/access) code for openfire server. I have successfully installed and configure ant in  my pc.

My basic question is : how to make openfire server to work according to our needs?

I am very new to all this so kindly share any good tutorial or material regarding customized XMPP server. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about GCM CCS and those things. For openfire development you should look at writing plugins to openfire. One can use openfire API to write plugins to extend the functionality of the server. Have a look at existing plugins and [plugin development](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/openfire/docs/latest/documentation/plugin-dev-guide.html) using openfire.

If your need is to change the functionality of the server. You have already build the server. The source code is there, just look into your required module, start placing logs first, touch minimal functionality and then change it according to your needs. Check the license schemes as well.